# Pointer Decay with Higher Precedence Than Template Function?

Tags: g++, c++17

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T& v) { //version 1
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void foo(char* v) {//version 2
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void foo(const char* v) {//version 3
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    char s1[] = "1234";
    const char* s2 = "2345";
    foo(s1);
    foo(s2);
}
```

The output is:

```
void foo(char*)
void foo(const char*)
```

I thought `s1` needs to go through pointer decay and so the template function `foo()` is a better match.

If I remove the 2nd `foo()`'s declaration and definition, then compiler chooses not to go through pointer decay and chooses the template function `foo()`.

Now, I am confused what the rule is for compiler to choose which function to bind to/call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is governed by overload resolution rules, which are quite complicated. A good write-up can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

For your particular case, a non-template function `foo(char* )` with implicit conversion wins over template function.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So if the non-template function `foo(char*)` with implicit conversion wins over the template function (I believe it is because of rule #4 "F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a template specialization" in Best Viable Function section).  However, after removing version 2 (the middle `foo()`), why rule #4 doesn't apply and so version 3 (non template function with implicit conversion) wins?  The only difference is the extra const quantifier in version 3.  Thanks.

Comment: @HCSF because a pointer to const char is not the same as const pointer.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more?  Because `char s1[]` isn't a pointer to const char nor const pointer.  So I am confused how compiler choosing the template version (version #1) relates to "a pointer to const char is not the same as const pointer".  Thanks.

Comment: @HCSF `char s1[N]` is decayed to a pointer to `char`. Note that the pointer is to a non-const char. At this point, a const reference to pointer to non-const char becomes a better match.